# Flutter : How to Use Linear Progress Bar with percentage while uploading file to storage

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload, progress-bar, firebase-storage

I have just developed an app which user can upload his/her document to firebase storage via camera or library itself. Here is my code block :

```
     class _DocUploadScreenState extends State<DocUploadScreen> {
         //Active ImageFile

             File _imageFile;

        //FireBaseStorage Initialize

           FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

       // Upload Image to Storage

           Future uploadImage() async {
           Reference _reference = _storage.ref().child('foyler/');
           UploadTask _uploadTask = _reference.putFile(_imageFile);
            }

         //Pick Image

           Future _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
           / ignore: deprecated_member_use
             File selected = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);

              setState(() {
              _imageFile = selected;
                      });
                          }

                 // Remove Image

                     void _clearImage() {
                     setState(() {
                     _imageFile = null;
                        });
                           }
```

I can able to pick image via camera or library and then upload to storage successfully. My concern is that I want to add linear or circular progress bar which shows progress of the uploading with percentage and then after it hits %100 percentage it will automatically direct to new page

Please let me know how ı can do this since I am stucked with progress indicator.

Answer (score 0):

in  `firebase_storage v. 4.0.1` putFile returns a type `StorageUploadTask`  which provides a handy stream `events` that you could listen to and get totalBytes and transferedBytes from it to calculate progress

```
final x = ref.putFile(File(a));

      x.events.listen(
        (event) {
          final currentPercentage = event.snapshot.totalByteCount * event.snapshot.bytesTransferred / 100;
          
        },
      );
```

After getting this you should just use it in a streamBuilder as required

Pd: `LinearPercentIndicator` widget receives a `value` from 0 to 1, where 1 represents 100% of the percentage

Comment: Luis I can able to get this but progress indicator is not working . Please advice

Comment: _uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
      _progress = taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred.toDouble() /
          taskSnapshot.totalBytes.toDouble();